# How to use solveset with several inequalities

Tags: sympy, inequality

How can I use sympy.solveset to solve a set of inequalities? I tried this:

```
from sympy.abc import x,y
from sympy import solveset, S
print(solveset([x > 2, x-1 < 3], x, S.Reals))
```

it should return something like:

```
2 < x < 4
```

However, it gives an error:

```
ValueError: [x > 2, x - 1 < 3] is not a valid SymPy expression
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use solveset but reduce_rational_inequalities instead.
There is my code:

```
from sympy import Symbol
from sympy.solvers.inequalities import reduce_rational_inequalities
x = Symbol('x', real=True)
reduce_rational_inequalities([[(x - 2 > 0),(x-1<3)]], x)
```

This gives the output you want :

> (2 < x) & (x < 4)